# Time Complexity of the "in" in python for the following code

Tags: python, list, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

```
arr1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
arr2 = ["x","y","z","c"]

obj = dict()

for i in range(len(arr1)):
    if arr1[i] in obj:
        continue
    else:
        obj[arr1[i]] = "true"

print(obj)

for j in range(len(arr2)):
    if (arr2[j] in obj):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

I am trying to loop through an array(arr2) and check if the array item is in the dictionary(obj) (created in the first for loop). Here i am using "in" to check whether it is in the dictionary(obj). What is the time complexity of the "in". Is it O(n), if so then there will be 2 nested for loops which will make it O(n^2).

I wanted the time complexity of the above problem as O(n). Is there any other method if this solution gives O(n^2) time complexity?

Comment: dictionaries are hash maps. Worst case, they are O(N) but average case O(1)

Comment: The average time complexity for data structures like List and Tuple is O(N).For 
Dictionary and Set average time complexity is O(1) because it uses hash table to store their element(key) and in worst case, it takes O(N) when there is hash collision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity would be O(1) on average, with the worst case being O(n)

[reference](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)